# Compile new kernel on debian wheezy

Tags: linux, kernel, debian

I'm trying to compile the 3.8.11 kernel on Debian 7.0 Wheeze. I'm using [this](http://verahill.blogspot.ru/2013/02/342-compiling-kernel-38-on-debian.html) tutorial,
but have a strange issue on the last step:

> sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.8.11_3.8.11-10.00.Custom_amd64.deb

fails with missing dependencies:

> linux-headers-3.8.11 depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.7).

But i already have libc6 of newer version installed on my system. The "dpkg -l | grep libc6" command returns

> ii  libc6:amd64  2.13-38  amd64
>
> ii  libc6:i386   2.13-38  i386
>
> ii  libc6-amd64  2.13-38  i386
>
> ii  libc6-dbg:amd64 2.13-38 amd64
>
> ii  libc6-dev:amd64 2.13-38  amd64
>
> rc  libc6-i386  2.13-38  amd64
>
> ii  libc6-i686:i386  2.13-38   i386

I have both i386 and amd64 versions because of skype.

Can my 3.8.11 headers be confused because of this plethora of libc6 versions?
What can I do with this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergey,
I'll try to give you an answer, although since I haven't seen this error myself can't validate the answer.

In brief, it may be due to your libc6-amd64 package. See whether anything still depends on it, and remove it.

See the following for more information: http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/01/msg00435.html

I should add that while I have multilib set up (and skype installed, just like you) dpkg -l|grep libc6 returns the following packages as being installed for me: libc6, libc6:i386, libc6-dev, libc6-i386 and libc6-i686:i386. This would support the thesis in [1](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/01/msg00435.html) since the only package 'missing' is libc6-amd64.

Comment: Verahill, yes indeed. The problem was with my multiarch mess of libc6 libraries. I've just successfully installed this kernel. Thanks a lot!